# How can I open a video to a specific point in the video?

Tags: java, android, video

I have an array of times that correspond to events in a recorded video. These times inflate a list. When a list entry is selected, I want the video to open to the time selected

Right now, the following code only opens the video at the beginning of the video.

```
                Uri video = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/recordedMedia/" +eventName+ ".mp4");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                intent.setDataAndType(video, "video/*");
                startActivity(intent);
```

Ideally directly at the specified time would be best, although starting at the beginning, then skipping to the specified time, would work too, if it is fairly quick.
I'm working with Android 2.2, API 8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the `seekTo()` method from the  `MediaPlayer` object?

I haven't tested this and you'll need to add in exception handling, but you could go for something along these lines:

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/recordedMedia/" +eventName+ ".mp4");
    mp.prepare();
    mp.seekTo(/*a time*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the MediaPlayer class in your own code.  The way you've done it will use the default player for the media type or one of the user's choosing.  Even if you could figure out how to make that particular media player start from a certain position, you have no chance of getting it to work with the wide variety of players in use, including some devices where the Android defaults have been replaced with OEM variants.

Create your own activity using a MediaPlayer and use seekTo() to start from your desired position. There are loads of examples on the web.

Cheers